# Create WordPress posts from JSON array using plugin in admin

Tags: plugins, admin, ajax, wp-insert-post, json

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that I'd like to do the following:

1. Add a WordPress plugin admin page that contains a button
2. When you click the button, it loads an array of JSON objects from a file, then creates a WordPress post for each object

I got #1 done, and I can see the array of JSON objects loading upon button click since I use `console.log`. (I made the button using [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pO-FYVZv94#at=2164) - uses AJAX.)

But, how would I go about giving WordPress access to the JSON array so I can create posts using `wp_insert_posts`? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here I assume your json is an array of object where properties are named like `wp_insert_post` [arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post): 'post_title', 'post_content' and so on.

```
function process_ajax() {  
    if ( ! isset($_POST['nonce']) || ! wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'mynonce') )
       die('error on checking nonce');  
    if ( ! isset($_POST['filepath']) die('no file given');
    if ( ! file_exists($_POST['filepath']) ) die('invalid file given');
    $posts = json_decode( file_get_contents($_POST['filepath']) );
    $done = 0;
    if ($posts) { 
      foreach ( $posts as $post) {
        $post = (array)$post;
        if ( isset($post['ID']) ) unset($post['ID']);
        if ( wp_insert_post($post) ) $done++;
      } 
      $str = "Successfully insert " . $done . "posts, ";
      $str .=  ( count($posts) - $done ) . ' failed.'
      die($str);
    } else {
      die('File contains not valid Json.');
    }
  }
```

Comment: But how would this work upon button click? Right now I'm using `.submit()` on the button in a JS file.

Comment: See my edit and follow your tutorial for the rest.